# getting XML info into SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, import

Hi Im trying to get some info from an XML file into my  MSSQL db, can anyone spot the errors.

Here is my sql code (now fixed with loop that goes through an entire directory and error trap)

Use mydb

```
IF OBJECT_ID('mydb..tempList') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE tempList

CREATE TABLE tempList ([FileName] VARCHAR(500))

--plain vanilla dos dir command with /B switch (bare format)
INSERT INTO tempList
EXEC MASTER..XP_CMDSHELL 'dir C:\Data\icecat\xmls /B'


--delete the null values
DELETE tempList WHERE [FileName] IS NULL

-- Delete all the files that don't have xml extension
DELETE tempList WHERE [FileName] NOT LIKE '%.xml'

--this will be used to loop over the table
alter table tempList add id int identity
go

truncate table dbo.XMLImportRelated --in case you want to rerun just this codeblock

DECLARE @Directory varchar(100)
SELECT @Directory = 'C:\Data\icecat\xmls\'

DECLARE @FileExist int
DECLARE @FileName varchar(500),@DeleteCommand varchar(1000),@FullFileName varchar(500), @SQLFullFileName varchar(500)

DECLARE @ProductID int  
DECLARE @RelatedID int
```

--This is so that we know how long the loop lasts
    DECLARE @LoopID int, @MaxID int
    SELECT @LoopID = min(id),@MaxID = max(ID)
    FROM tempList

```
WHILE @LoopID <= @MaxID
BEGIN

SELECT @FileNAme = filename
FROM tempList
WHERE id = @LoopID

SELECT @FullFileName = @Directory + @FileName

EXEC xp_fileexist @FullFileName , @FileExist output
IF @FileExist =1 --sanity check in case some evil person removed the file
BEGIN

DECLARE @x XML, @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
BEGIN TRY 
SELECT @sql = N'SELECT @X = CONVERT(xml,[ICECAT-interface],2) 
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ''' + @FullFileName + ''' ,SINGLE_BLOB)
 ---------------------^^ escaped quotes are important  
 AS Import([ICECAT-interface]);';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@x XML OUTPUT', @x OUTPUT;

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH  
PRINT 'Error'  
END CATCH

INSERT XMLImportRelated ([ProductID],RelatedID)

select P1.X.value('@ID', 'int') as ProductID,
        P2.X.value('@ID', 'int') as RelatedID


 from @X.nodes('/ICECAT-interface/Product') as P1(X)
      cross apply P1.X.nodes('ProductRelated') as PR(X)
      cross apply PR.X.nodes('Product') as P2(X)


 -- SET @DeleteCommand = 'del ' +  @Directory + @FileName
END


SELECT @LoopID = min(id)
FROM tempList
WHERE id > @LoopID
END
```

and here is a url to the xml im trying to use

http://www.metatronics.co.uk/XML/3326091.xml

thanks guys I keep getting nulls so its something small im missing but after looking at it all morning im going crazy,
John.

Comment: The url you provided is asking for a user name and password so I couldn't see the file. What is your table structure?

Comment: Sorry here is a bit of the file the related bit is at the bottom

Comment: ARRRRgh its too long http://www.metatronics.co.uk/XML/3326091.xml this location wont ask for and credentials i moved it

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RelatedProducts](
 [Product ID] [int] NULL,
 [Prod_id] [varchar](50) NULL,
 [ThumbPic] [varchar](150) NULL,
 [Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
 [Supplier ID] [int] NULL,
 [Supplier Name] [varchar](150) NULL

Answer (score 0):

In the XML you have provided there are four attributes in `/ICECAT-interface/Product/ProductRelated` and `path` is not one of them.

Try:

```
SELECT
  Product.value('@ID', 'int'),
  Product.value('@Category_ID','int'),
  Product.value('@Reversed','bit'),
  Product.value('@Preferred','bit')
FROM ...
```

If you instead wanted to pick the attributes from `/ICECAT-interface/Product/ProductRelated/Product` you need to change the `nodes` clause to include `Product` and specify the attributes that are used there in the field list.

To get the values from both ProductRelated and Product you should use `cross apply`.

```
select PR.X.value('@ID', 'int') as ProductRelatedID,
       PR.X.value('@Category_ID','int') as Category,
       PR.X.value('@Reversed','bit') as Reversed,
       PR.X.value('@Preferred','bit') as Preferred,
       P.X.value('@ID', 'int') as ProductID,
       P.X.value('@Prod_id', 'nvarchar(500)') as Prod_id,
       P.X.value('@ThumbPic', 'nvarchar(500)') as ThumbPic,
       P.X.value('@Name', 'nvarchar(500)') as Name
from @X.nodes('/ICECAT-interface/Product/ProductRelated') as PR(X)
  cross apply PR.X.nodes('Product') as P(X)
```

**Update:**

```
select P1.X.value('@ID', 'int') as ProductID,
       PR.X.value('@ID', 'int') as ProductRelatedID,
       PR.X.value('@Category_ID','int') as Category,
       PR.X.value('@Reversed','bit') as Reversed,
       PR.X.value('@Preferred','bit') as Preferred,
       P2.X.value('@ID', 'int') as ProductID,
       P2.X.value('@Prod_id', 'nvarchar(500)') as Prod_id,
       P2.X.value('@ThumbPic', 'nvarchar(500)') as ThumbPic,
       P2.X.value('@Name', 'nvarchar(500)') as Name
from @X.nodes('/ICECAT-interface/Product') as P1(X)
  cross apply P1.X.nodes('ProductRelated') as PR(X)
  cross apply PR.X.nodes('Product') as P2(X)
```

Result:

```
ProductID   ProductRelatedID Category    Reversed Preferred ProductID   Prod_id            ThumbPic                                        Name
----------- ---------------- ----------- -------- --------- ----------- ------------------ ----------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------------------
3326091     57050234         258         0        0         1220634     WS-C2960-24-S      http://images.icecat.biz/thumbs/1220634.jpg     Catalyst 2960-24-S
3326091     68385107         258         0        0         2708530     WS-C2960-48TC-S-RF http://images.icecat.biz/thumbs/2708530.jpg     Catalyst 2960-48TC-S
3326091     57050235         258         0        0         1220633     WS-C2960-24TC-S    http://images.icecat.biz/thumbs/1220633.jpg     Catalyst 2960-24TC-S
3326091     57050236         258         0        0         3328069     WS-C2960-24PC-S    http://images.icecat.biz/thumbs/3328069.jpg     WS-C2960-24PC-S
3326091     0                182         0        0         16646       DFE-690TXD         http://images.icecat.biz/thumbs/16646.jpg       32 Bit Card Bus 10/100Mbps Ethernet Adapter with Direct Port
3326091     57050238         258         0        0         1710023     WS-C2960-48TT-S    http://images.icecat.biz/thumbs/1710023.jpg     Catalyst 2960-48TT-S
3326091     0                182         0        0         468298      LC102              http://images.icecat.biz/thumbs/468298.jpg      LAN PC Card Gigabit
3326091     57050239         258         0        0         1220632     WS-C2960-48TC-S    http://images.icecat.biz/thumbs/1220632.jpg     Catalyst 2960-48TC-S
3326091     0                883         0        0         1549666     UT012                                                              UTP Cable Cat5E 3M Grey
3326091     57050233         258         0        0         1710024     WS-C2960-8TC-S     http://images.icecat.biz/thumbs/1710024.jpg     Catalyst 2960-8TC-S
3326091     0                182         0        0         1959688     LC103              http://images2.icecat.biz/thumbs/1959688.jpg    Gigabit Network Card PCI Express
3326091     57050237         258         0        0         3326672     WS-C2960-24LC-S    http://images.icecat.biz/thumbs/3326672.jpg     CATALYST 2960 24 10/100 Port & 8 PoE
3326091     0                244         0        0         1320852     BR-6624            http://images.icecat.biz/thumbs/1320852.jpg     BR-6624 Load Balancing Router
3326091     0                182         0        0         489937      LC101              http://images.icecat.biz/thumbs/489937.jpg      Gigabit Network Card PCI
3326091     0                182         0        0         72364       DGE-530T           http://images.icecat.biz/thumbs/72364.jpg       32-Bit 10/100/1000 Base-T PCI Adapter
3326091     0                1505        0        0         1318217     N-707522           http://images.icecat.biz/thumbs/1318217.jpg     UTP Crimping Tang
3326091     0                244         0        0         1684822     20002427           http://images2.icecat.biz/thumbs/1684822.jpg    FRITZ!Box Fon WLAN 7270 International Edition
3326091     0                883         0        0         1318218     N-707523           http://images.icecat.biz/thumbs/1318218.jpg     UTP CAT5 Pullbox Network Cable, 100m
3326091     0                1172        0        0         1318117     N-707521           http://images.icecat.biz/thumbs/1318117.jpg     UTP Shieldcaps for RJ45, 10 Pieces
3326091     0                244         0        0         859910      20002387           http://images.icecat.biz/thumbs/859910.jpg      FRITZ!Box Fon WLAN 7170 Annex A
3326091     0                244         0        0         859908      20002388           http://images.icecat.biz/thumbs/859908.jpg      FRITZ!Box Fon WLAN 7170 Annex B
```

Comment: Thanks Very Much Mikael, I have been messing around and that is nearly there.  Can I Select data from different nodes in one select statment ie one bit from product and one from product/productrelated

Comment: Thanks again Mikael I appreciate your time, Im going to be back messing with this tomorrow, I will update you.

Thanks again

John.

Comment: Hi Mikael I have one more question if you dont mine. Further up the XML document under ICECAT-interface/Product is a value 'ID' that I would like to prefix each line of my results so I know which product ID the related ID's refer to. can I just cross apply another node or would you go about this in another way. if you could just point me in the right direction I would appreciate that, I need to work some of this out myself. :)

Comment: @JohnSpencer You just need an extra cross apply. Easier to show in code so I updated the answer :).

Comment: Just what the doctor ordered, that works just as i wanted, I see you can just keep adding multiple cross apply's.

Comment: No on to looping through all of my files :)

Comment: @JohnSpencer  going through files in tsql? Sounds like another question. Probably answered somewhere in here already.

Comment: I have had a good go I think im really close I have changed the code above can you spot any errors it seems to be looping but nothing is getting into the table.

Comment: I used this guide for the looping http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/how-to-import-a-bunch-of-xml-files-from-

Comment: @JohnSpencer the XML part looks ok. I have not tested the other stuff.

Comment: Cracked it Mikael (with help from you and a few others thankyou)